# Oracle: unable to change to noarchivelog

Tags: oracle

We discovered that our Oracle 12c database was taking up a large amount of disk space with archive logs, so I figured out how to delete the files, but I'm unable to disable archive logging.  We don't have an in-house DBA, so I'm trying to figure this out myself.  From lots of Googling, it's my understanding that I need to do the following:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
shutdown immediate
startup mount
alter database noarchivelog;
alter database open;
```

I've got two problems though.  I can't do the "sqlplus / as sysdba", it complains about "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error" unless I specify the SID, even though it the environment variable is defined.  Also, when I do the shutdown, I get "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor" and it disconnects me from Oracle.

```
C:\Users\administrator.MYDOMAIN>set oracle_sid=orcm

C:\Users\administrator.MYDOMAIN>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Feb 5 11:11:33 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect / as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


SQL> connect sys/password@orcm as sysdba
Connected.
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> archive log list;
Database log mode              Archive Mode
Automatic archival             Enabled
Archive destination            E:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\RDBMS
Oldest online log sequence     6869
Next log sequence to archive   6871
Current log sequence           6871
SQL> shutdown immediate
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really need to get a DBA. If you did succeed in turning off archive log, then you would give up the ability to do point in time recovery. Did your last DBA create a backup job in Windows scheduler? Do you know where the backups are being written? Do you know when the last successful backup completed? If you are stuck I have worked with Oracle on Windows for over 15 years, I would be happy to help you. just send me a private message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error` on Windows is typically caused by incorrent `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` environment variables.

Find the database service:

[image]

Find the path and name of the instance:

[image]

Based on that:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=O:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set ORACLE_SID=RTG
```

Then try again:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
shutdown immediate
startup mount
alter database noarchivelog;
alter database open;
```